# I am not sure what is going on with the for loop through GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void Update(){
    GameObject[] BoxArray = new GameObject[16]{BoxLid1, BoxLid2, BoxLid3, BoxLid4, BoxLid5, BoxLid6, BoxLid7, BoxLid8, BoxLid9, BoxLid10, BoxLid11, BoxLid12, BoxLid13, BoxLid14, BoxLid15, BoxLid16};

    for(int i = 0; i < BoxArray.Length; i++){
        Transform theBoxLid = BoxArray[i].transform;
        BlueBox.transform.Translate(theBoxLid.localPosition.x, theBoxLid.localPosition.y, 0);
        Debug.Log(theBoxLid.localPosition.x);

    }
}
```

I have the Lids initiated above thats not the problem. I want the blueBox to move over the BoxLids in the array but it is not moving at all.

I have found a solution for this and it is:

```
IEnumerator MoveBlueBox(){
    GameObject[] BoxArray = new GameObject[16]{BoxLid1, BoxLid2, BoxLid3, BoxLid4, BoxLid5, BoxLid6, BoxLid7, BoxLid8, BoxLid9, BoxLid10, BoxLid11, BoxLid12, BoxLid13, BoxLid14, BoxLid15, BoxLid16};

    for(int i = 0; i < BoxArray.Length; i++){
        Transform theBox = BoxArray[i].transform;
        BlueBox.transform.position = new Vector3(theBox.position.x, theBox.position.y, 0.0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
}
```

I am taking the BlueBox and making it lay on top of every box in the BoxArray every 0.1 seconds by looping through the array and changing the BlueBoxs transform position. The main thing i found out was that i need to use a "new Vector3" to correctly move the box to every box in the BoxArrays x, y, and z coordinates.

Comment: is it supposed to be `localPosition.x, localPosition.x` instead of `x, y`?

Comment: that was a typeo on my part in my code it is that

Comment: we need to see the code for transform and translate

Comment: @CodingYoshi those are build into unity - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

Comment: Transform.Translate only moves the objects position with said amount, not the actual position.

Comment: @cory sparks What do you mean by "move over"?

Comment: Make sure you don't mess things up with local/world space. For example, if BoxLid is at 0, 0, 0 in localPosition (relative to its parent) and BlueBox is at 0, 0, 0 as well (with another parent, or within world, wherever), it will translate **by** zero amount, so will stay in place.

Comment: @Mark okay so now the x never changes and the y changes by an extraordinary amount, within second it is at 30,000.

Comment: It's time to learn what local space and world space are then, along with what exactly Translate does ;)

Comment: @corysparks Your question needs revising, its unclear what you want or/and the code snipit is misleading.

Comment: @corysparks have you had any luck finding a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: No everyone's saying to not put it in the update and not use a for loop but idk what else to use other then a for loop. For each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerator MoveBlueBox(){
    GameObject[] BoxArray = new GameObject[16]{BoxLid1, BoxLid2, BoxLid3, BoxLid4, BoxLid5, BoxLid6, BoxLid7, BoxLid8, BoxLid9, BoxLid10, BoxLid11, BoxLid12, BoxLid13, BoxLid14, BoxLid15, BoxLid16};

    for(int i = 0; i < BoxArray.Length; i++){
        Transform theBox = BoxArray[i].transform;
        BlueBox.transform.position = new Vector3(theBox.position.x, theBox.position.y, 0.0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
}
```

I figured it out thanks to the people that actually tried to help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still unsure what you mean by "move over". Do you want to move your bluebox first to BoxLid1, then BoxLid2 etc.?

Also to make you Box look like its moving you need to update your position only a little bit each time `Update` is called. You can do that various ways, an example would be the `MoveTowards` function of `Vector3`:

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject boxLid1;
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    public void Update() 
    {
        BlueBox.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
            BlueBox.transform.position, boxLid1.transform.position,
            Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

This would move your `BlueBox` towards your `boxLid1` with a certain speed until it reaches it. Also note that this is sample code and I have not testet this.